# How to export PDF from data of datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

How can I export the data from `DataGrid` into PDF? The quick solution.

```
<DataGrid Name="table" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" IsTextSearchEnabled="True" Background="White">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Timestamp" Binding="{Binding StartDate}" SortDirection="Descending" SortMemberPath="StartDate" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding Title}" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}" IsReadOnly="True" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Type" Binding="{Binding Tag}" IsReadOnly="True" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use iTextSharp (http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) to generate datagrid to pdf.

(or) Look at http://wpfextendeddatagrid.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can use iTextSharp to do it. You can add DataGrid visual in iTextSharp Document and use its PdfWriter to write it to the pdf file.

Below is the simple tutorial on it.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/f2e803/basic-pdf-creation-using-itextsharp-part-i/